# How to loop through dynamically added elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which adds/removes elements (via AJAX) depending on what type of item the user wants to submit. It includes `div` elemets which have the `contenteditable="true"` attribute enabled so that users can type in to a div.

When submitted the form to the server, I need to loop through all the elements that have the attribute `contenteditable="true"` and send the data across. I do gathering of data like this:

```
$('form #Publish, form #Delete').on('click', this, function(e) {
      var FormToSubmit = $(this).parents('form'); // form to submit
      var ButtonClicked = $(this); // which button was clicked publish or delete?
      var serialisedFormArrayObject = [];
      serialisedFormArrayObject.push({
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        value: $(this).val()
      });

      // loop through contenteditable elements
      var $contentEditableItems = $("[contenteditable=true]"); // this doesn't work on dynamically added elements
      $contentEditableItems.each(function(index) { // add data from elements to form data
        serialisedFormArrayObject.push({
          name: $contentEditableItems[index].id, // ID of div
          value: $contentEditableItems[index].innerHTML // html inside of div
        });
      });
    }
```

The code above works fine when the page already has the contenteditable div elements on the page. But if they are dynamically brought in, it doesn't seem to catch them in the `var $contentEditableItems = $("[contenteditable=true]");` part of the code.

How can I get these elements that exist after the page has loaded?

I add the elements via AJAX which goes to the server and asks it for HTML code. The code returned by the server will be like this:

```
<div id="Hobbies" contenteditable="true">
 <p>List your hobbies here.</p>
</div>
<div id="Qualifications" contenteditable="true">
 <p>List your qualifications here</p>
</div>
```

The above gets added to the form dynamically. I don't do any adding/removing of properties/attributes in jQuery.

Comment: where are you calling this code?

Comment: It depends on how you call the loop. suppose you add the new elements in the DOM then put this code in a function and call that function.

Comment: @kiranvj I just added the trigger code. It happens when the user clicks on `Publish` in the form

Comment: Use a class selector on them instead

Comment: @Jai I need it to happen when the user clicks on `Publish` button

Comment: @charlietfl can you provide an example as an answer please?

Comment: @volumeone how are you adding contenteditable elements? can you provide an snippet of that code?

Comment: not complicated... `<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">` ... `var $contentEditableItems = $(".editable");`

Comment: @volumeone Can you try `$("[contenteditable='true']");`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for that. Out of interest, why does jQuery pick up dynamic elements by class name and not by attribute?

Comment: One problem is `$('form #Publish').on('click', this, function(e) {` isn't valid. Second argument needs to be a selector. What is `this`?

Comment: There is something wrong here that we can't see. Need a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: @charlietfl the `this` is the button clicked. i added a bit more code so you can see why I need it.

Comment: No, `this` is only the button **inside** the handler. Should not be adding `this` as second argument of `on()`

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for those elements inside the event handler and not storing a reference to them on page load?

Comment: I think the problem is not that the selector does not work, but the function is not run, because the buttons which the function is bound to are probably replaced by ajax content, too. A simple console.log would demonstrate it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I just fixed it by adding `$(document).on('click','form #Publish, form #Delete', function(e) {
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're replacing the elements you bound on, the binding is gone. So replace your binding with:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Publish, #Delete', function(e) {
  let $clickedElem = $(e.target).closest('#Publish, #Delete'),
      $contentEditableItems = $("[contenteditable=true]");

  console.log($contentEditableItems.length);

})
```

Now your code will work, even after you replace your form contents (including the `#Publish` and `#Delete` buttons).

In conclusion: they container selector (the one you bind on) has to stay in the markup. If you replace it, you lose the binding. `$(document)` might be too general as container selector (but it's guaranteed to work). Feel free to change it to a more specific one, but make sure it's an element that remains in the page throughout the entire life cycle of your page.

Comment: @volumeOne, I'll create an example where instead of using `$.ajax` I'll add the items from a variable. I'm not sure right now, but it might have to do with the fact you're passing `this` (which I assume to be the window object) as child selector of your `click` event. Why is it there in the first place?

Comment: `this` tells me what button was clicked. I have added a bit more code to make it clearer.

Comment: That's not how you get the clicked button. You get the button from `$(e.target)`! `this` passed as you did, is the outer scope of your binding function, most likely the `window` object.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu nothing wrong with using `this` inside handler. Is safer actually than target because target can be a child of this. currentTarget ===this

Comment: @charlietfl I think he should try what I'm saying. And for safety, he could use `let eventTarget = $(event.target).closest(childSelector)`

Comment: Is overkill when `$(this).closest` will return exactly the same thing. Personally I think something else not shown is wrong

Comment: I agree that `currentTarget === this` ***inside the binding function***. But `this` is also the execution context outside of that function and that's what it references in the above code. You might be right about the cause being something else. Gotta love JS. :)

Comment: @volumeone, could you please test what I'm suggesting? If that's not the cause, as charlie suggests, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Andrei I worked out that the problem was this which you came to in the end `$(document).on('click','form #Publish, form #Delete', function(e) { });`

Comment: It means you were replacing the button, too. And there went your entire function. That was what was not "working", not the "selector". Nothing would have worked, because the function was not executing after you replaced the buttons.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes a schoolboy error but in that case why isn't everything in jQuery acting on the document in the first place? What advantage is there ever of having `$(#Publish).on('click', function(){});` over `$(document).on('click', #Publish, function() {});` ?

Comment: @volume, from jQuery docs: *"Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements."* I've also mentioned it the answer.

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to be sure that the dynamically added content also has `contenteditable='true'` as you can make it editable only by `contenteditable`

I think the below code would be more secure to get all the editable contents;

```
var $contentEditableItems = $("div[contenteditable]").filter(function() {
   return $(this).prop('contenteditable');
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add a common class to all you editable div, like :

```
<div class="content_editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then use class `.` selector  like :

```
var $contentEditableItems = $('.content_editable');
```

Comment: Out of interest, why does jQuery pick up dynamic elements by class name and not by attribute?

Comment: I think you got down-voted for lack of substance of your answer. It should be crystal clear that adding a class does not change anything. `$('[contenteditable]')` or `$('[contenteditable=true]')` are just as valid selectors for the element you posted above. Your answer basically says: *"I don't know why your selector does not work."*. Considering your reputation and the answer quality one expects from someone like you, as well the fact your answers should guide by example, I'm tempted to down-vote myself, to be totally honest.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be case sensitive code. Your dynamicly added code might use a capital where your static code doesn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').append('<div contenteditable="True">test1</div>');
  $('#test').append('<div contenteditable="False">test2</div>');
  $('#test').append('<div contenteditable="True">test3</div>');
  $('#test').append('<div contenteditable="true">test4</div>');
  $('#test').append('<div contenteditable="frue">test5</div>');
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $('[contenteditable="True"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
})

$('#button2').on('click', function(){
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
<button id="button">Log True (Capital)</button>
<button id="button2">Log true (No capital)</button>
```

Comment: This assumes OP is using attribute to set new ones. Doesn't explain why OP's code not working. This isn't an answer...just a comment

Comment: @charlietfl Don't have an example how to code is added. A typing mistake might be the reason since the selector works like a charm. Therefore my answer.